# Use levenshtein distance for keys in defaultdict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, levenshtein-distance

I am doing some sequencing analysis, and i'm trying to create a default dictionary of genetic sequence based on some identifiers. So looking at the following example, I have created a dict, and put both sequences `AGAGAG` and `ATATAT` in the same list because they have the same identifier of `CCCCCC`:

input:

```
CCCCCCAGAGAG
CCCCCCATATAT
```

code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d['CCCCCC'].append('AGAGAG')
d['CCCCCC'].append('ATATAT')
```

The problem I have is that if the key sequence is within a levenshtein distance of 1 I want it to be treated as the same key. So if I come across a sequence that looks like this:

```
CCCCCTACACAC
```

I want to look through the dict and see that there is `CCCCCC` and see that `distance('CCCCCC', 'CCCCCT') < 2` so maybe change `CCCCCA` to `CCCCCC` and then append to the same list as above.

Hopefully there is a good way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: For your example do you mean `distance('CCCCCC', 'CCCCCT') < 2`?

Comment: Are you saying the first six chars are the keys? Also can the strings be literally any combination of letters?

Comment: If you'd consider every string with every string in terms of LD, then you're going to be doing way too many computations. Most importantly is to first of all sort all the links. You should probably sort on each index of the 'CCCCCC'-length string, and then compare a couple of near strings (if we're talking about millions of strings). The definition of "a couple" depends on how big your set is. Anyway, in that case you have to do only relatively few comparisons.

Comment: One issue I can see with this is that it's non-commutative. If your original key is CCCCCC, it would match CCCCCT and TCCCCC, but if the original key is CCCCCT, it would match CCCCCC but not TCCCCC.

Comment: Yea, it is not a nice property that depending on how you start, you'll most likely end up with different keys.

Comment: How large is the input?

Comment: You might want to look at something like a fuzzy dict, as implemented by pywinauto here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/fuzzydict.py

Comment: @TheNightman With that input, you won't be able to use the accepted answer most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `difflib.SequenceMatcher` which returns 1 for equal sequences and you can use your difference for compare :

In this case :

```
>>> import difflib
>>> difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,'CCCCCC', 'CCCCCT').ratio()
0.8333333333333334
```

Demo :

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> import difflib

>>> li=['AAAAAAACDCBA', 'CCCCCCATATAT', 'CCCCCCAGAGAG', 'CCCCCTACACAC', 'AAAAAAACACAC']
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in li:
...     d[i[:6]].append(i[6:])
... 
>>> keys=d.keys()
>>> for i,j in combinations(keys,2):
...      if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,i, j).ratio()>0.8:
...         d[i].extend(d[j])
...         del d[j]
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'AAAAAA': ['ACDCBA', 'ACACAC'], 'CCCCCC': ['ATATAT', 'AGAGAG', 'ACACAC']})
>>>
```

Comment: Don't think the OP is asking how to calculate, they are asking how to use a single key for multiple similar strings

Comment: If the input is too large, you won't be able to make all the Levenshtein distance computations. (1000x1000 comparisons takes 0.6 seconds, 10k by 10k takes over a minute....)

Comment: @PascalvKooten Yes, I know this is not a good way for bigger sequences of  strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy
biginput = [''.join([chr(y) for y in numpy.random.randint(65, 90, 6)]) 
            for x in range(100000)]
biginput[0]
'VSNRGF'
```

I'm thinking you have to somehow create ~6 sortings, so that for each key you have to only make a couple of comparisons. This is possible, since the Levenshtein would only need to consider a couple of variations.

In fact, you'll need some form of LSH (Locality sensitive hashing). Perhaps someone can help further.